# Initializing sftp subsystem via libssh2

Tags: php, sftp, libssh2

I am trying to get a file from a remote sftp server in a php script. I'm using the libssh2 library anI have been able to 1) open a connection to the ssh server and 2) authenticate properly. I'm hitting a wall on creating an sftp resource for use with the ssh2_sftp* functions and wrapper. The following line leaves $sftp as NULL:

> ```
>       $stfp = ssh2_sftp($ftp_conn);
> ```

Php error log shows no errors. Ssh server logs show successful login, authentication, and log the sftp subsytem being initialized. Any ideas on where to look next?

Comment: Maybe you could try phpseclib and enable logging to see what's going on? I find phpseclib better for diagnostic purposes. Actually, I just find it better for just about everything lol but one step at a time.

Comment: It does look easier to use. I may switch over to that. Still, on the principle of the thing, there aught to be a way to make this work.

Comment: There might be but I think it'd be harder to figure out with libssh2. If you can provide the phpseclib logs that might potentially provide some insight into the libssh2 problem as well.